# ng-repeat duplicate issue, when there are not any duplicates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
$scope.subjects = [
    "Computer Security", "Graphics and Multimedia",  
    "Networks", "Computer Science and Engineering", "Game Design",  
    "Programming", "Information Technology", "Software Engineering",  
    "Technology Management", "Telecommunications", "Web Development",  
    "Environmental Sciences", "Biology", "General", "Aviation",  
    "Mathematics", "Engineering"];  


<label class="concentration-label3" ng-repeat="subject in subjects">
  <input type="checkbox" name="concentrations" class="concentration-label3__input js-concentration-value" value="" data-mixpanel-subject="Design">
  <span class="concentration-label3__title" for="conc1">
    {{subject}}
    <span class="concentration-label3__title__checkmark4"></span>
  </span>
</label>
```

> Issue: Error: ngRepeat:dupes Duplicate Key in Repeater

Comment: But i am facing duplicate issue. And your plunkr link contains hellow plunkr script...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a track in your ng-repeat:

```
<label class="concentration-label3" ng-repeat="subject in subjects track by $index">
```

Comment: There i was doing a mistake some where else but your answer was informative.